# A more efficient way of doing a 'single word match' check between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query which returns all records in table 1 where one full word in a field matches the field name in table 2. So for instance, if I had a field in table 2 called "brown", a field name in table 1 of **"the quick brown fox"** would be returned in the results, but a field name of **"thequickbrownfox"** would not as it is not a single word in the field name.

```
select distinct [SpecNumber], [SpecName], sc.[SpecCrosscheckName] from [SpecSummary] ss
    INNER JOIN [SpecCrosscheck] sc
        on ss.[SpecName] = sc.[SpecCrosscheckName] or
           ss.[SpecName] like '% ' + sc.[SpecCrosscheckName] + ' %' or
           ss.[SpecName] like '% ' + sc.[SpecCrosscheckName] or
           ss.[SpecName] like sc.[SpecCrosscheckName] + ' %'
        order by sc.[SpecCrosscheckName]
```

This returns the results as expected, but the inner join is convoluted so is taking over 3 minutes to run. Is there a more efficient way of getting the same results? As far as I'm aware there is no way to merge the like statements into one, and I'm not convinced that this would improve the performance anyway.

I have looked into using `CONTAINS` but I don't believe a field name can be used as a search criteria in this function?

**Extra info:**
SpecCrosscheck contains just one field, a list of one-word names ("James", "Boris" etc). The "SpecName" field in SpecSummary contains full names (for instance "David James", "Joe Bloggs"). I want to return all results in SpecSummary where one word in the full name is an identical match of any record in SpecCrosscheckName (so with the above examples, "David James" would be returned but "Joe Bloggs" would not).

Comment: I think sample data and it's explanation with desired result is highly required here. Please provide some if you can

Comment: @Suraz Made an edit - hope that clarifies things.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
ss.[SpecName] like '%' + sc.[SpecCrosscheckName] + '%'
```

is the same as all of the rest combined, so just ise this.

EDIT: Didn't spot the spaces, my bad.

Comment: This doesn't accommodate for where the names are an exact match, or where the matched field is at the very beginning or end (as the criteria searches for an empty space either side of the value).

Comment: You are wrong @finjo, just try out what JohnHC said ... you'll get same result as with your query

Comment: Except for an exact match because of the spaces add after and before, no ?

Comment: I tried it and I did not. As I said, following on from the example in my question, a field value of **"brown fox"** would not be a match for "brown" because the query becomes `code`ss.[SpecName] like '% brown %'`code` - which would not be returned due to there being no empty space at the beginning.

Comment: @JohnHC 'thequickbrownfox' would now be classed as valid which I don't want. I have been going round in the same circles myself :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you can compare the columns by removing space between the words so if I am right then you can achieve through REPLACE function as below:

```
REPLACE(ss.[SpecName], ' ', '') = REPLACE(sc.[SpecCrosscheckName], ' ', '')
```

OR, you can use below for the partial comparison also

```
REPLACE(ss.[SpecName], ' ', '') LIKE '%' + REPLACE(sc.[SpecCrosscheckName], ' ', '') + '%'
```

Complete query will be as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [SpecNumber], [SpecName], sc.[SpecCrosscheckName] 
FROM [SpecSummary] ss
INNER JOIN [SpecCrosscheck] sc 
ON REPLACE(ss.[SpecName], ' ', '') LIKE '%' + REPLACE(sc.[SpecCrosscheckName], ' ', '') + '%'
ORDER BY sc.[SpecCrosscheckName]
```

Comment: This is returning results for where the field is across two words, so for instance a field value 'bro wn' would be considered a match for 'brown'. However this seems to be on the right track as it took 2 and a half minutes to return 3815 results (compared with 3 mins 10 secs to return 919 with the old query)... I'll work on adjusting this to try and get rid of the 'search result across two words' problem... Let me know if you have any ideas of how I could do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding leading and trailing space,

```
select distinct [SpecNumber], [SpecName], sc.[SpecCrosscheckName] from [SpecSummary] ss
    INNER JOIN [SpecCrosscheck] sc
        on ' '+ ss.[SpecName] +' ' like '% ' + sc.[SpecCrosscheckName] + ' %' 
        order by sc.[SpecCrosscheckName]
```

though this will work as desired, your original query would run faster!

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below script.

```
select distinct [SpecNumber], [SpecName], sc.[SpecCrosscheckName] from [SpecSummary] ss
    INNER JOIN [SpecCrosscheck] sc
        on  LTRIM(RTRIM(ss.[SpecName]))  like '%' +sc.[SpecCrosscheckName]+ '%' 
        order by sc.[SpecCrosscheckName]
```

Comment: Having the same problem as I did with Suraz's answer here....the performance is significantly better, however it is no longer removing partial results which was my intention with the original query. I'm struggling to think of a way to incorporate LTRIM/RTRIM and ensure there are only single word matches at the same time.